# Is it totally safe to unset $_SERVER?

Tags: php, environment-variables, unset

As we know `$_SERVER` provides some information about the environment of the server to us and sometimes it's not reliable.

We can overwrite or `unset()` the `$_SERVER` like other variables and arrays.

But is it totally safe to unset this var in PHP?

Comment: Yes, because it's just server and execution environment information, created by the web server. My question is, what is your goal?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe" ? I don't recommend using them to store your own data, since they can be overwritten by the server.

Comment: Unlike `$GLOBALS`, `$_SERVER` doesn't have any special significance for PHP itself. But it'll probably compromise your ability to use third-party libraries. And it won't make the values really unavailable (you can still do e.g. `filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'PHP_SELF')`). Plus memory savings will be negligible. It'd be useful to know what you want to accomplish exactly.

Comment: I want to make a sandbox that lets clients run PHP codes, but I want to restrict them from checking some of the server information.